# How i get external CSS value From external JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna to get  ***element background value*** from javascript file.
I has three files -

1. html.html
2. css.css
3. js.js

html.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> I'm Button! </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="myBlock" onclick="heyJS()"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

css.css

```
.myBlock {
  width: 300px; max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px; max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 100px; 
  font-size: 50px; font-weight: lighter; font-style: normal; text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px; position: relative;
  background-color: #83DF31;
}
```

js.js

```
function heyJS() {
    alert(document.getElementsByClassName('myBlock')[0].style.backgroundColor);
}
```

After running the scrpit,I only get blank alert box.

How can i get ***div background value*** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your alert() with this

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myBlock')).backgroundColor);
```

or

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('myBlock')[0]).backgroundColor);
```

And modify your html a little bit if you using the first one.

```
<div id="myBlock" class="myBlock" onclick="heyJS()"></div>
```

Comment: Thank brother,why not working in `alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('myBlock')).backgroundColor);`

Comment: Well, good question :) But I guess it is defined in that way. You will find more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".myblock")).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```